# How to use eigen to rewrite numpy's array comparing function

Tags: c++, numpy, eigen

I have a piece of numpy code.

```
distance = np.ones((N,)) * 1e10
mask = dist < distance     
distance[mask] = dist[mask]
```

l think the distance and dist is a array.through comparing the value of distance and dist,I want to find a smaller value and store that in distance.
In c++,I can only do this with a for loop.Does eigen have a function to implement this operation.thanks!!

I can only do this with a for loop. I hope to find a function of eigen to implement this operation.

Comment: In numpy the array comparison returns an array of bools - results of comparison of corresponding elements in 2 arrays (print `mask` to see the results in your case). Then expression `someArr[mask]` selects elements under indices where `mask[i]` is true. So your piece of python code basically does the following: `if(dist[i] < distance[i]) distance[i] = dist[i];`

Comment: As for "I can only do this with a for loop" - I don't see any reason for you to do it differently in C++, at least not until you discover a bottleneck.

Comment: That is just `distance = dist.cwiseMin(1e10);` (or just `dist.min(1e10)`, if `dist` is an `Array`).

Comment: And for more complicated expressions look at `select`: https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1DenseBase.html#a65e78cfcbc9852e6923bebff4323ddca

Comment: Sorry，I didn't describe the problem clearly. "select" function is what I need.thanks!!